# Euler's method scheme python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Edit: The function is u[t]=[[0, 1], [-6,5]]*u with an initial condition of u(0)=[[1], [1]]. The exact answer is u_t=[[1],[2]]*2*e**(2*t)-[[1],[3]]*e**(3*t)

I am working on a project and I am lost as to why this is not working. I am planning on running an Euler's method scheme on the following code.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def Eulm():

    x0=0
    y0=1
    z0=1
    n=21
    xf=2
    y0=1
    z0=1
    w0=y0
    q0=z0
    w = [0] * (n+1)
    q = [0] * (n+1)
    w[0]=w0
    q[0]=q0
    x=np.linspace(x0,xf,n)
    y=2*np.e**(2*x)-np.e**(3*x)
    z=4*np.e**(2*x)-3*np.e**(3*x)
    L=[0]

    for i in range (1,n):
        deltax=(xf-x0)/(n-1)
        y0=y[0]
        z0=z[0]
        A=np.matrix([[1, -deltax], [6*deltax, 1-5*deltax]])
        G=np.linalg.inv(A)
        print(G)
        b=np.matrix([y[i-1], z[i-1]])
        b=b.transpose
        w[i]=G[0][0]*w[0][i]+G[0][1]*q[0][i-1]
        q[i]=G[1][0]*w[0][i-1]+G[1][1]*q[0][i-1]
        plt.plot(x,y)
        plt.xlabel('Time')
        plt.ylabel('Numerical Solutions')
        plt.title('Numerical Solutions with respect to Time')
        plt.show()
```

I got the following error, and I am unsure why I am getting this error, considering that it should be iterating through the list.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-da43a543ec92> in <module>()
----> 1 Eulm()

    <ipython-input-47-022f3e9099b9> in Eulm()
         29         b=np.matrix([y[i-1], z[i-1]])
         30         b=b.transpose
    ---> 31         w[i]=G[0][0]*w[0][i]+G[0][1]*q[0][i-1]
         32         q[i]=G[1][0]*w[0][i-1]+G[1][1]*q[0][i-1]
         33         plt.plot(x,y)

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `w` is a 1D-array, thus a double-index would try to subscript access a scalar value. Maybe `w[i]` is all that you want.

Comment: I tried what you said, and now I'm running into an indexing errorIndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1 at line 31

Comment: The same thing applies to `q[0][i-1]`

Comment: Can you explain the math behind this a little bit? Then we'll be able to help you better. This doesn't look like the canonical y'=f(t,y) , y(x_t)=x_t Euler's method example.

Comment: Btw, I think you just have to get rid of `[0]`s in `w` and `q` so:
`w[0][i]` -> `w[i]` and `q[0][i-1]` -> `q[i-1]`. Also it's better to access `G`s elements as `G[0,0]`, not `G[0][0]`

Comment: This is a differential equation, so it has two separate components. I just realized that I didn't add two pictures that may help, which I am going to do in a couple of seconds. Basically, I am looking for the inverse of A, then multiplying that matrix by the previous iterations. I tried getting rid of the [0] terms everywhere I had it, but I was unable to get it to run the way it was supposed to with an actual series of answers and graph(s). I will also need to find the error between the exact and the calculated, but I have no idea how I am supposed to start that yet, as the code doesn't work.

Comment: Tried to add pictures, but I think the pictures were too big. I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks to everyone's support, I have the code working well. Is there an easy way for finding the error using the functions already in place? Thank you again in advance!

Comment: If you need help with a different aspect of your code please ask a new question instead of using comments.

Answer (score 0):

There are a large number of problems with your code/theoretical implementation of the Euler method. Here's a simple version of `eulm` that does what it's supposed to:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def eulm(n=2001):
    x0=0
    y0=1
    z0=1
    xf=2
    wq = np.zeros((n, 2))
    wq[0] = y0,z0
    x = np.linspace(x0,xf,n)
    y = 2*np.exp(2*x) - np.exp(3*x)
    z = 4*np.exp(2*x) - 3*np.exp(3*x)
    A = np.array([[0, 1], [-6, 5]])
    dx = (x[1] - x[0])

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
    ax = fig.gca()
    ax.set_xlabel('Time')
    ax.set_ylabel('Numerical Solutions')
    ax.set_title('All Numerical Solutions with respect to Time,\n%d timesteps' % n)

    for i in range (1,n):
        wq[i] = wq[i - 1] + dx*(A @ wq[i - 1])
        if i == n-1:
            # add a legend in the final display
            ax.plot(x, wq[:, 0], c='C0', label='approx y')
            ax.plot(x, wq[:, 1], c='C1', label='approx z')
            ax.legend()
            fig.show()
        else:
            ax.plot(x, wq[:, 0], c='C0')
            ax.plot(x, wq[:, 1], c='C1')
            fig.show()

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
    ax = fig.gca()
    ax.set_xlabel('Time')
    ax.set_ylabel('Numerical Solutions')
    ax.set_title('Final Numerical Solutions with respect to Time,\n%d timesteps' % n)
    ax.plot(x, wq[:, 0], ':', c='k', lw=3, zorder=99, label='approx y')
    ax.plot(x, y, c='C2', lw=15, label='exact y')
    ax.plot(x, wq[:, 1], '--', c='k', lw=3, zorder=99, label='approx z')
    ax.plot(x, z, c='C3', lw=15, label='exact z')
    ax.legend()
    fig.show()

    return wq, x, y, z
```

I rolled `w` and `q` into a single two column array `wq`. I got rid of the inverse matrix `G` (I couldn't figure out what you were trying to do with it, and in any case its not a part of the [standard Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method)). I simplified the calculation of the value of `wq` at the next time step using some matrix notation stuff from Numpy (the `@` operator was recently added to Numpy, and functions as a matrix multiplication operator).

For large enough `n` (and so a small enough time step `dx`), the estimated values in `wq[:, 0]` and `wq[:, 1]` converge to the exact values in `y` and `z` with a small error (around `~1%` when `n=2001`). Here's what the plots that `eulm()` produces when you run it look like:

[image]

[image]